# Validate text field value if its blank

Tags: javascript

I have a text field 'Comments' in the data table, if the field is blank then call the update function , once the field has some value, then don't append any other value. 
Basically UPDATE should happen only if the field is blank. 
I tried to pick the length of  the field and check if its greater than '0' then call update function but what I can see is I am able to insert and save the field value but its appending more than once. 
how can I validate?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: how should we help without code/context... ?

Comment: *"Basically UPDATE should happen only if the field is blank."* - Do you mean the update should happen only if the field has an unsaved *non*-blank value but previously was blank?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if the field is blank, perform the update operation. If it already has value contained in it, don't append any value to it but just restrict the user by sending an alert from adding any value if it already has values.

Comment: *"if the field is blank, perform the update operation"* - If the field is blank, what value are you setting it to? Please [edit] your question to clearly distinguish between values the user is seeing/editing on screen and values already in the database. (Assuming you're talking about a database.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $('input')
    .on('change', check)
    .on('blur', check);

  if (!$('input').val()) {
    $('input').val('Text');
  }

  function check() {
    if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val() === '') {
      $(this).val('Text');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>
```